# Does healthy or strong go first when used together?

Tags: adjectives, word-order, adjective-phrases, adjective-order

> He is a **strong healthy** man.

> He is a **healthy strong** man.

Which is the correct answer and why?

Comment: Correct *answer* to what?  What is *the question*?

Comment: @Victor Bazarov, OP refers to the sequence of the adjectives "healthy" and "strong".

Comment: Yes it's **"strong healthy"** which is common. I will explain it later.

Answer (score 3):

**Short Answer**

Both in American and British corpus, there are entries for this order - **strong healthy**, and no entry for the reverse order of these two words.

The correct order is - **strong healthy**.

**Long Answer**

*Grammatical Explanation :-*

Adjectives occur in noun phrase. Within noun phrase, the correct position of adjective is between the determiner and the head noun.  
But what if there are more than one adjective present? We need to learn the correct ordering of adjectives.

In order to determine the order of adjectives it's convenient divide the territory between the determinative and the head noun into four premodification zones (I, II, II, IV).

So the structure of the noun phrase is -

> Determinative + [*Zone I* + *Zone II* + *Zone III* + *Zone IV*] + head-noun

**Zone I** : *Precentral* 
Examples of adjectives that will sit in this zone are:

i) *Emphasizers -* Example - certain, definite, plain, pure, sheer etc. 
ii) *Amplifiers -* Example - absolute, entire, extreme, perfect, total etc.
iii) *Downtoners -* Example - feeble, slight etc.

**Zone II** : *Central* 
 Examples of adjectives that will sit in this zone are: *new, good, nice, long, beautiful* etc.

The adjectives in this zone must satisfy the four criteria - 
 
i) They can sit in attributive position. Eg: "a *cold* day" etc. 
ii) They can sit in predicative position. Eg: "The day is *cold*" 
iii) They can take *comparative* and *superlative* form. It can be achieved by means of inflection or by addition of *more* and *most*. Eg: *colder*, *coldest* etc. 
iv) They can be premodified by the intensifier - *very*. Eg: "very *cold*" etc.

If there are more than one adjective in central position, the general order is -

> NONDERIVED (Ex: *good, bad, strong* etc) + DEVERBIAL (Ex: *interesting* etc) + DENOMINAL (Ex: *angry, rainy, peaceful, healthy* etc)

Within the class of NONDERIVED adjectives the order is -

> SIZE + LENGTH + HEIGHT

That's why we prefer *a small round table* to *a round small table*

When we have some EMOTIVE adjectives (Eg: *lovely, nice, wonderful* etc), it generally precedes other central adjectives.

Example - *beautiful worm* weather.

**Zone III** : *PostCentral* 
 Examples of adjectives that will sit in this zone are:

i) *Participles -* Eg: retired, working etc. 
ii) *Colour adjectives -* Eg: blue, dark etc.

**Zone IV** : *Prehead* 
 Examples of adjective that will sit in this region are:

i) Adjectives with a proper noun basis denoting nationality, provenance and style. Example: *American, Gothic* etc. 
ii) Other adjectives with a morphological or semantic relation to nouns often with the meaning "consisting of", "involving" or "relating to". Example: *annual, social, economic* etc. 
iii) Nouns. Example: "*tourist* attraction", "*college* student" etc.

So the right order is - *strong healthy*

*Non grammatical approach -*

In order to be *strong*, you have to be *healthy*. So it's *strong*[*healthy* man]. But it's very unlikely that in order to be *healthy*, you have to be *strong*.

<sub>Reference - A comprehensive Grammar of English Language 17.113</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Based on the source:
https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/adjectives/order-adjectives

> Adjectives usually come in this order: General
> opinion, Specific opinion, Size,  Shape, Age, Colour, Nationality, Material.

"Strong" and "healthy" are under 'Opinion'; hence, we differentiate which one is general and which one is specific.

Again, from the source:

> Some adjectives give a general opinion. We can use these adjectives **to describe almost any noun.**
>
> E.g., good, bad, lovely, strange, beautiful, nice, brilliant, excellent, awful, important, wonderful, nasty
>
> Some adjectives give a specific opinion. We **ONLY use these adjectives to describe particular kinds of noun**
>
> E.g., Food: tasty; delicious
> Furniture, buildings: comfortable; uncomfortable
> People, animals: clever; intelligent; friendly

I believe that strong is general and healthy is specific. i.e., we can use both adjectives to humans, animals, economy, etc. but I cannot say "healthy wall" or "healthy keyboard" (which provides that 'strong' has a broader scope than 'healthy'.) [I am sure there are other considerations here, but I am answering based on the common usage of "strong" and "healthy", we say, "strong building", not "healthy building". "Strong odour", not "healthy odour".]

So the answer would be, **"He is a strong healthy man."**

Kindly note that there is no rigid rule on specifying which is broader between the two, so we also encounter, "He is a healthy strong man." (Again, I based the above reason on common usage.)