# Small naughty kid or naughty small kid?

Tags: adjectives, adjective-order

I wonder if I should say "he ate the chocolates like "a small naughty kid" or "a naughty small kid"?

Naughty is an specific idea and small is about size, so I guess it should be the second one. But somehow, I feel it is awkward to say so. Which one is correct?

Also, is "a jagged wide scar" correct?

Comment: I think both **naughty small kid** and **small naughty kid** is fine. **small naughty kid** => *naughty kid* who is *small*. **Naughty small kid** => *small kid* who is *naughty*. For grammatical analysis http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/65027/3463 From grammatical point of view it's **small naughty kid**.

Comment: Sorry I was wrong. The preferred order is **naughty small**. And this is what grammar says. For more read my answer in that link.

Answer (score 2):

I think most people would say "naughty little kid".

"jagged wide scar" would be correct if the scar itself is wide and it is jagged. If the jags themselves are spreading all over the place, it would be a "widely jagged scar". If you want to use these words.

Comment: I agree about "little kid". In AmE, "small kid" doesn't sound right. But for the scar, "wide, jagged scar" would work just as well. They are both physical qualities, thus neither has inherent priority.  http://www.grammar-quizzes.com/adj_order.html

Comment: Yes, I think the comma and the different order sound better overall.

Answer (score 0):

Adjectives usually come in this order.
1. general or specific opinion 
2. size 
3. shape
4. age
5. color
6. nationality
7. material
So, with this order, the first answer is  "naughty small kid" 
For the second one, "Jagged" goes for the shape and "wide" goes for the size.
the second one is "wide jagged scar"

Comment: Interesting, I had never seen this rule/convention articulated like this. I agree with your proposed versions of the examples, but as has been pointed out, "little" is preferable to "small."